# Xamarin Test Recorder options have errors. Unable to record an automated test

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, ui-automation

All of the settings in "Options->Xamarin->Xamarin Test Recorder" have errors. I have Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise) along with Xamarin and Xamarin Test Recorder plugins installed on my desktop. I'm unable to set this options. See attached picture for error. [Xamarin Test Recorder Options page][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJJEd.jpg

In addition, the lightening bolt, that allows one to record a test, does not appear in the UITest (Test.cs) page. I believe the two are related and would am interested in solving the first issue, which should resolve the second. (I think?) 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the reason, but the installation of the extension does not work, it does not put all the dlls it depends on to function, to work must [download](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f9171f80-291e-480c-8003-8bf5c575f2dc) and uncompress VSIX inside it has another VSIX, install it, and will work.

[image: File open VSIX with 7-zip]

Comment: Thank you Erli! :) I was double clicking on the Test Recorder "vsix". My machine kept telling me that Test Recorder was already installed. However, once I unpacked it and then ran the vsix, it installed again.. Now I see the lightening bolt! And the errors are gone.